# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^4-3n^3-n^2+2n-1}{n^5+n^4-n^3-3n^2-3n+1})^{(\frac{6n^5-2n^4-2n^3+n^2-2n}{9n^4-2n^3+n^2+3n})}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{n^4-3n^3-n^2+2n-1}{n^5+n^4-n^3-3n^2-3n+1}\bigg)^{\big(\frac{6n^5-2n^4-2n^3+n^2-2n}{9n^4-2n^3+n^2+3n}\big)}$$

I have tried to formulate it to a form of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ but did not manage, how should I approach this?

Comment: Is there a plus or minus in the middle of $3n^3n^2$? Please check the statement carefully!

Comment: Fixed it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking out the highest powers of $n$ you can see that the expression looks like

$$\left(\frac 1n\cdot a_n \right)^{n\cdot b_n }$$

With $a_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} 1$ and $b_n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \frac 69 = \frac 23$.

So, you have

$$0\leq\lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{n^4-3n^3-n^2+2n-1}{n^5+n^4-n^3-3n^2-3n+1})^{(\frac{6n^5-2n^4-2n^3+n^2-2n}{9n^4-2n^3+n^2+3n})}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac 1n\cdot a_n \right)^{n\cdot b_n } \leq \lim_{n \to \infty}  \left(\frac 1n\cdot a_n \right)^{b_n } = 0$$

Comment: Why in the last inequality the expression without n is $\leq$?

Comment: Because, if you have a number $0<x<1$, then you have $0<x^n < x$ for $n>1$. Since we are taking the limit, we have only $\leq$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the base of your exponential goes to $0$ (not $1$), so the limit is not of the form $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. On the other hand it can be written as
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^{nb_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp\left(nb_n\ln\left(\frac{a_n}{n}\right)\right)$$
where $a_n\to A$ and $b_n\to B$ with $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^+$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it will behave as
$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^{6n/9} \rightarrow 0^{\infty}\rightarrow  0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n)>0$, then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)^{g(n)}=0,$$ which is easily proven by noting that $a^x$ is a decreasing function of $x$ whenever $a<1$, and creating an eventual upper bound for $f(n)^{g(n)}$ based on this. By then taking $$f(n)=\frac{n^4-3n^3-n^2+2n-1}{n^5+n^4-n^3-3n^2-3n+1},$$ $$g(n)=\frac{6n^5-2n^4-2n^3+n^2-2n}{9n^4-2n^3+n^2+3n},$$ we immediately get to the conclusion that the limit is $\boxed{0}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio $0^\infty$ isn’t actually an indeterminate form, even though it definitely looks like one. My argument holds the same.

Comment: OK I seemed I think wrongly. $1^\infty$ should be the indeterminate form lol